# Check if function returns true Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I am wanting to check that when a function returns a true value then `NSLog(@"hello!!!");` Just to confirm, I wish to check that `validUrl` returns `true`. I have declared the controller that it is inside, and this is the complete code:

```
NewInAppWebViewController *webViewController = [[NewInAppWebViewController alloc] init];

        if([webViewController validUrl:(NSURL *)url] == true) {
            NSLog(@"hello!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            [self showAlertForExternalURL:url];
        }
```

Below is the function:

```
- (BOOL)validUrl:(NSURL*)url {
    NSString *stringURL = [url absoluteString];

    if([stringURL length]==0){
        return false;
    }

    NSString *regExPattern = @"www-(test|testing[a-z]|newtest)\.testerer\.com";

    NSRegularExpression *regEx = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:regExPattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    NSUInteger regExMatches = [regEx numberOfMatchesInString:stringURL options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringURL length])];

    NSLog(@"%i", regExMatches);
    if (regExMatches == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

Pass `NSURL` to method parameter and call method as follows:

```
NewInAppWebViewController *webViewController = [[NewInAppWebViewController alloc] init];

NSURL *url=yourNSURLHere;

  if([webViewController validUrl:url]) {

     NSLog(@"hello!!!");
  }
  else{

     [self showAlertForExternalURL:url];
  }
```

Comment: Apologies, you was correct regarding passing the url. How did I not see this haha! Thanks.

Comment: WC...HTH@DaveDavidson